# In Django's shell, how can I load ipython magic functions automatically?

Tags: django, ipython

I want to make the following ipython commands permanent when using django shell:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Unfortunately, Django doesn't seem to use my global ipython config, so putting them in my default_profile doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to have these executed automatically when running django shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [django extentions](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/) package, which contains a `shell_plus` command.  This command autoloads the models, but you also can use the `--notebook` attribute.  There you can add the autoload parameter: `--ext django_extensions.management.notebook_extension`.

See [here](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/shell_plus.html) for more info.